# Excel: Duplicate Merging

Tags: excel, duplicates, excel-2010

So I've got an incredibly large contact list, originally an export from Outlook so it follows the same formatting. I've an incredibly large number of duplicates down to records holding the same name, but separate addresses / mobile numbers.

I'm looking for a macro that can help me merge these duplicates so I don't lose things like different addresses under the same name.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EaI6e.png

In this case I'd love a macro to see that A3 is a duplicate of A2, so take J3 to O3 and paste these in Q2 to V2. Then repeat this process for any duplicate pair found.

Comment: That's nice. Good luck finding one.

Comment: What have you tried and what errors is it receiving? If you're looking for someone to write a macro for you, try contacting a software development firm and paying for it.

Comment: Are there any other fields you want to move, or literally just `J3:O3`.  Also, realize that if you do this, then their Home Addresses will actually have business addresses, without any note.

Comment: Also, what happens if there are 4 rows of the same name? Paste into `Q2:V2` for the first duplicate, then `W2:AB2`?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit rudimentary, but it works.  Note, since you didn't say what should happen where there are more than 2 duplicates, this macro won't really work if that's the case.

```
Sub moveDuplicates()
Dim i As Integer, lastRow As Integer
Dim primaryRange As Range, copyToRange As Range, cel As Range, cel2 As Range, rng As Range
Dim ws      As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet

'First, sort by "Key" to get duplicates all in a row

With ws.Sort
    .SortFields.Clear
    .SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
                         "A2:A" & ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
                    xlSortNormal
    .SetRange Range("A1:P" & ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count)
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With


lastRow = ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count
Set rng = ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, 1), ws.Cells(lastRow, 1))

Dim lastDupRow As Integer, startDupRow As Integer, copyRow As Integer

For Each cel In rng
    'First, see if the cell has a duplicate anywhere, if not, then goto next cel
    cel.Select
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, cel.Value) > 1 Then
        Debug.Print "Duplicate exists"
        'So, since we know a duplicate exists, we need to copy the duplicate rows' info.
        startDupRow = cel.Row + 1
        lastDupRow = ws.Columns(1).Find(cel.Value, searchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
        If lastDupRow - startDupRow = 0 Then
            copyRow = lastDupRow
        Else

        End If
        For Each cel2 In ws.Range(Cells(startDupRow, 1), ws.Cells(lastDupRow, 1))
'            pasteRange(cel.Row).Select
'            copyRange(cel2.Row).Select
            pasteRange(cel.Row).Value = copyRange(cel2.Row).Value
            copyRange(cel2.Row).EntireRow.Delete
        Next cel2

    End If
Next cel

End Sub

Private Function copyRange(ByVal iRow As Integer) As Range
    Set copyRange = Range(Cells(iRow, 10), Cells(iRow, 15))
End Function

Private Function pasteRange(ByVal xRow As Integer) As Range
    Set pasteRange = Range(Cells(xRow, 17), Cells(xRow, 22))
End Function
```